# Object reference not set to an instance of an object in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: vb.net, winforms, .net-4.0

I am trying to make a program that takes a text from a file and writes it into a label in visual studios 10. I want to be able to click buttons on the exe to make it go from the previous line to the next line and vise versa. I am storing the text into an array and then making the label equal the text on the given part of the array. I am receiving the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." Can anyone help ? thanks. here is part of my code my code:

```
   Private Sub BrowseButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles BrowseButton.Click

            Dim UserInput As DialogResult = Browser.ShowDialog()

            If UserInput = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel Then
                Return
            End If

            FileOpen(1, Browser.FileName, OpenMode.Input)
            Do While Not EOF(1)
                Input(1, InternalTextFile(Index))
                Index += 1
            Loop
            FileClose(1)
            Output1Text.Text = InternalTextFile(Index)
            Output2Text.Text = InternalTextFile(Index + 1)

    End Sub
```

The error arises On the line `Input(1, InternalTextFile(Index))`

Comment: Why are you using vb6 file access APIs in .Net? Those exist only for migrating legacy code, and should be avoided entirely for new developement.

Comment: WHat code do you suggest then sir?

Comment: See here for some basic .NET IO stuff, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304427

Comment: We need more information about your InternalTextFile array. As it is, it looks like you're reading past the end of the array for Output2Text, and so it's hard to know what you intend here.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more code it's hard to tell, but if the error is on `Input(1, InternalTextFile(Index))`, its likely that the variable `InternalTextFile` was never assigned a value. Something like this maybe?

```
Dim InternalTextFile As New List(of String)
Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(Browser.FileName)
Try
    Do 
        InternalTextFile.Add(reader.ReadLine)
    Loop Until reader.Peek = -1
Finally
    reader.Close()
End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like maybe you want something like this:

```
Private Sub BrowseButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles BrowseButton.Click
    If Browser.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel Then Exit Sub

    Dim InternalTextFile() As String = File.ReadAllLines(Browser.FileName)
    Output1Text.Text = InternalTextFile(InternalTextFile.Length - 2)
    Output2Text.Text = InternalTextFile(InternalTextFile.Length - 1)
End Sub
```